# Based on Array index value style the HTML element

Tags: angular

I wanted to style the html elements based on array index value > 4

```
<div *ngFor="let e of arr ; let i = index" > 
(i > 4 ) ? <p [ngClass]="['clr']" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': 'blue'}"> {{e}} </p>  :  <p> {{e}} </p> 
</div>
```

I wanted to check condition inside the loop. But it just printed as string with out checking condition.

Comment: Read through this article - you will get the answer - https://ng2.codecraft.tv/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/

Comment: Can someone please help me to understand what is wrong in my approach. why it is printing string without checking the condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve it is using `*ngIf`

```
<div *ngFor="let e of arr ; let i = index">
    <p *ngIf="i > 4" [ngClass]="['clr']" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': 'blue'}"> {{e}} </p>
    <p *ngIf="i <= 4"> {{e}} </p> 
</div>
```

Another is to use conditional classes using `ngClass`

```
<div *ngFor="let e of arr ; let i = index">
    <p [ngClass]="{'clr-blue' : i > 4}"> {{e}} </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The least verbose way would probably be to simply put the conditional inside the ngClass or ngStyle statement.

```
[ngClass]=" i > 4 ? 'whateverClass' : 'whateverOtherClass'"
```

or

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color' : ((i > 4) ? 'blue' : 'red') }"
```

Or any variation of these